# Community modified *how*?

Tags: discussion

I see, as I write this, two posts here on meta that were modified by Community 4 and 6 hours ago. Yet visiting them I see no comments or edit notices and it appears that nothing has happened in a month.

Thus is frustrating because I look at the changes specifically. How do I know what to react to?

Can somone in the know explain how these were touched without leaving any trace other than a tantalizing note implying that I should find something new/different?

Answer (score 4):

That's the Community "bump".  Periodically, though I'm not sure what the period is on metas, a script runs that looks for an old, open question with at least one answer but no upvoted answers, and bumps it up to the top again.  The idea is to get more eyes on it -- were those answers ok but overlooked?  Are they not ok and somebody can do better?

Related on Meta.SE: [How can we make the purpose of Community "bumping" more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279203/how-can-we-make-the-purpose-of-community-bumping-more-obvious)